# document.write versus document.getElementById().innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a script that creates two sets of forms - each set has 12 forms and each of these has a drop-down input menu

I have two questions:
1. When I use document.getElementById().innerHTML instead of document.write I don't get the same appearance. 2. Using document.write - How can I make the second set of forms float to the left?

TIA

Here is the code:

```
 var names = ["Sun", "Moon", "Mercury", "Venus", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto", "MC", "Asc"]

 var signs = ["Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"]

 document.write("<body>") 

 for (j=0;j<(12);j++){
 document.write("<form id=" + "\"" + j + "\">")
 document.write("<select id=" + "\'" + j + "\'" + "onchange='OnChange();'>")
 for (i=0;i<(12);i++){
 document.write("<option value=" + i + " name=" + signs[i] + ">" + signs[i] + "</option>")
 }

 document.write("</select><input type=" + "\"text\"><input type=" + "\"text\">" + names[j] + "<br>")

 document.write("</form>")
 }
 document.write("<br>")
 document.write("<body>") 

 for (j=12;j<(24);j++){
 document.write("<form id=" + "\"" + j + "\">")
 document.write("<select id=" + "\'" + (j-12) + "\'" + "onchange='OnChange();'>")

 for (i=0;i<(12);i++){
 document.write("<option value=" + i + " name=" + signs[i] + ">" + signs[i] + "</option>")
 }

 document.write("</select><input type=" + "\"text\"><input type=" + "\"text\">" + names[j-12] + "<br>")

 document.write("</form>")
 }
 document.write("<br>")
```

Comment: `document.write` is outdated, it is a security vulnerability and it undermines the point of the DOM. Do not use it.

Comment: Use html when you can, and javascript when you need it. Your onChange function most likely is javascript, but the rest of this could be html markup.

Comment: also can't use `document.write` after initial page load without wiping out everything that's already in page

Comment: don't use document.write because whenever anybody looks at your code they'll start thinking that you're a Windows XP user on IE8 and that you don't know what "chrome" means

Comment: @Ingo Bürk this is for my personal use offline

Comment: @charlietfl - there is nothing that is already on the page - but I can add things after the document.write

Comment: @Markasoftware - nobody else will be looking at the code BTW I use Windows7, Windows Vista64, and WindowsXP with Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE7,8,9,10, and Opera

Comment: Could someone suggest to me a way of having the second set of forms float:left? Thanks

Comment: `<anytag style="float:left">`

Comment: @charlietfl - I had to add a div to encompass all of the forms - then float:left worked

Comment: i was just trying to say that document.write is outdated and everything @user2301129